# Add custom button to Form ControlBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how to add additional button to Form ControlBox that is present at image below:
[image: 1]

I know in this forum are few similar questions but no single one answered my question. I checked few links and its not that what i expected because its not working at every operating system. I checked those links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11510/Add-Transparent-Menus-and-XP-Titlebar-Buttons-to-y
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10171/Adding-a-Minimize-to-tray-button-to-a-Form-s-capti

Other idea is to change default click event and icon for MaximizeBox because i don't need this one in my app.

Comment: It is not a form control box, but a window (form) caption (title) buttons. I'd like to know answer on this question myself.

Comment: They call property as ControlBox and anyone can set it as invisible (all three buttons disappear) that's why i call it this name.

Comment: Messing with the window chrome was feasible 20 years ago.  It is over and done with, you'll never get it right on every Windows version.

Comment: @HansPassant I know it can be difficult or kinda easy but there must be any possibility to do this like at screen above. I have seen many applications which have 4 or more buttons like this.

Answer (score 1):

Scratch this - just realized it's a Winforms issue.

Kinda lame suggestion, but in WPF I'd do:
[image]

Drop the title

```
<Window> ... WindowStyle="None"  ... /<Window>
```

Then roll my own:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Content="Yo!"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Content="-"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Content="■"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Content="X"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Caveats:

You will have to do a mouse capture to move the window, not difficult but not trivial either. Also change the style of the buttons to look like the regular icons etc

Not ideal I know, but in a pinch ...

Comment: I know about it my friend. I know its possible, I can even made my own form extend native form, set border less and draw own border, add manually events. That solution isn't easy but will work. There is only one problem it will never looks like default, what isn't expected. There must be other way to do this many applications got it.